# When using CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource how reference an interface in the running project?

Tags: c#, .net, code-generation

I have some code that is running and generates an implementation of an interface at runtime. I am trying to use `CSharpCodeProvider` but when I try to compile code that has a class implementing an interface in the same code from the running application (which is running in debug mode in Visual Studio), it throws an exception:

> "The type or namespace name 'TestCodeGen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

My code:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform;

namespace TestCodeGen
{
    public class TestApp
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parameters.OutputAssembly = "MyImpl";

            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
                parameters,
                @"
                    using TestCodeGen;
                    public class MyImpl : IInterface
                    {
                        public string GetName()
                        {
                            return ""test"";
                        }
                    }
                "
            );

            IInterface impl = (IInterface) Activator.CreateInstance(null, "MyImpl");


        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(impl.GetName());
        }
    }

    public interface IInterface
    {
        string GetName();
    }
}
```

How would I add a reference to my interface and its namespace? Is there some way to use `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("WHAT_GOES_HERE?");`?

Comment: Probably something like `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35` You should look for the exact name/version

Comment: @J.vanLangen  I think this might work (looking into it): `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(TestApp).Assembly.Location);`

Comment: or `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(TestApp).Assembly.FullName);`

Comment: @J.vanLangen What's the difference between these two? Why is full name better?

Comment: Some assemblies should be loaded from the GAC, so a fullname which includes a version, will fix this aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the assembly that contains `IInterface`. You can use `typeof(IInterface).Assembly.Location`.

To create an instance of `MyImpl`, you first need to get the type using `results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("MyImpl")`

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

public class TestApp
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
        parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = "MyImpl";
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof(IInterface).Assembly.Location);

        CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
            parameters,
            @"
                    public class MyImpl : IInterface
                    {
                        public string GetName()
                        {
                            return ""test"";
                        }
                    }
                "
        );

        var myImplType = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("MyImpl");
        IInterface impl = (IInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(myImplType);


        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(impl.GetName());
    }
}

public interface IInterface
{
    string GetName();

}
```